# Update for Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal

I have been asked to update a program in Pascal.  I program is used to transfer data from one program to another,  What I need to know is what either state of the port mean?
**tTransferState = (sAbort, sWaiting, sFirstLine, sModelFeature, sOtherLines, sSending, sClosePort, sOpenPort, sPaused, sFinished);**  I have tried searching the internet and haven't found anything,  maybe I'm searching the wrong thing.  I know what some of these mean but not all.  I believe I can finish the program easy if I can find the meaning to each of these.

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: how should we know? they're just variable names. they could be "foo", "bar", "baz" and mean just about as much.

Comment: I can figure out what they were used for if I can find the states in there meaning.  I know sSending is for the state of sending data, that is when one computer is talking to another.  But does the state of the port go to finished when it is done and if so how long will it be in that state.  What I'm trying to figure out is I want to write on a form that I have opened what was just sent.  What state does the port need to be in.  I know it's not the Waiting or the paused state.

Comment: We have no idea, again because this is proprietary code which we have no idea how it's used. You might as well be asking us what your driver's license number is. Where did you get this snippet of code from?

Answer (score 1):

The code you are referring to is proprietary to your application's code. There is no standard for what these mean - it's up to your application to know what they mean. What are they? It's an [enum (or enumerated) type definition](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Enumerated_Types). But only the author(s) of this code knows the original intention. Usually, such types are documented somewhere for future developers to understand.

If such documentation is unavailable, I suggest doing a global search of your code to find the usage of each, and observe how they're being used in the context of the code around it. I also suggest documenting things, at least as code comments, as you go along. I've even seen big libraries such as Indy raise question in the code's comments.

Comment: I'm think he got this from Free Pascal, I not sure but I don't know where this guy left any documents to tell the meaning of anything he's done, but it is now my job to update these programs.  Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: What's so "not useful" about my answer that people feel the need to downvote? Why do people not bother to explain themselves?

Comment: @JerryDodge  I didn't down vote, in fact I rarely do.. I think a comment is much better.  In this case,  it's such a bad question, that it doesn't deserve an answer - your answer would make a better comment to his question imo.

Comment: @JohnEasley Same problem on another answer of mine today, both of which got a downvote in less than a minute of posting.

Comment: @JerryDodge, yes, but that one got a much improved question edit, and you were then up voted.  Improving poor questions should be a first priority...